# Schengen Question

Tags: schengen

My daughter is studying abroad over the summer and does not require a Visa. She entered the Schengen area on May 21st and will be leaving it on August 19th, which is 91 days (our bad - her dad and I are meeting her in Italy and traveling to Greece with her and I did not understand the 90-day rule). She is planning to travel to England/Scotland for a few days while in Italy. Can we subtract those days from the original 91 days? Thanks much.

Comment: I am sure this question will be closed as a duplicate but I have not yet searched for the question yet. Yes, she can, as long as she is not in the Schengen zone any part of those days. Leaving day and arrival day count as days in the Schengen zone.

Comment: Yes, outside of Schengen area the clock stops and resumes after reentry. This will be documented with the exit/entry stamps.

Comment: Thank you! I have looked for the question, but did not find this particular scenario. I appreciate that you took the time to answer. :)

Comment: Keep in mind that partial days in Schengen count full. At least one full day in England, better two in case something unexpected happens. Never a good idea to go all the way to 90 days.

Comment: I want to thank you all before my question is deleted as a duplicate. I appreciate your time and I feel much better about our situation now.